# What is the fastest scheme implementation?

Tags: lisp, scheme

Obviously, that will depend on what you want to do: numerical analysis, threading, databases, etc. I've seen the benchmarks; Larceny and Bigloo seem to come up ahead. Is there any implementation of Scheme that performs pretty well in several different benchmarks? Are there any that can create code that runs faster than produced by SBCL? I don't see why SBCL should be so fast - Scheme is a far simpler language than Common Lisp!

Comment: You asked "Which is faster Scheme or CL?" a few months ago and it was closed. What drives your need for the fastest Scheme implementation? Providing some details on the problem you're working on would probably help, since different implementations also have different built-in libraries.

Comment: Why don't you benchmark them and tell us what you find?

Comment: https://ecraven.github.io/r7rs-benchmarks/ (repo: https://ecraven.github.io/r7rs-benchmarks/)

Answer (score 8):

http://community.schemewiki.org/?Stalin

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalin_(Scheme_implementation)

From Wikipedia:

> Stalin (STAtic Language ImplementatioN) is an aggressive optimizing
>   batch whole-program Scheme compiler written by Jeffrey Mark Siskind.
>   It uses advanced flow analysis and type inference and a variety of
>   other optimization techniques to produce code. Stalin is intended for
>   production use in generating an optimized executable.
>
> The compiler itself runs slowly, and there is little or no support for
>   debugging or other niceties. Full R4RS Scheme is supported, with a few
>   minor and rarely encountered omissions. Interfacing to external C
>   libraries is straightforward. The compiler itself does lifetime
>   analysis and hence does not generate as much garbage as might be
>   expected, but global reclamation of storage is done using the Boehm
>   garbage collector.

It seems that `Stalin` is no longer being developed.

Answer (score 8):

Among the Schemes that are fully standards compliant (at least with R5RS) and ready for prime-time use, [Chez Scheme](http://www.scheme.com/) must be the fastest.

Comment: Chez Scheme is proprietary software

Comment: Chez Scheme is no longer proprietary software. It is available on github under an Apache 2.0 license.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [these benchmarks](https://ecraven.github.io/r7rs-benchmarks/), it looks like Chez Scheme, Gambit, and Racket are roughly tied for the title of Fastest Scheme.

Comment: The benchmarks specify "safe mode": in Chez Scheme, using `compile-whole-program` (cross-library inlining) and `optimize-level 3` (using Fixnum procs where possible) can make for a significant speedup (factor of 3 in my experience).